# Why we use dollar $ sign in code, how we reserve space in constant segment

Tags: assembly, x86-16

please help me in understanding what this code is trying to do. At line number 1014 it is declaring CONSTRT, equal to $ (doller sign), but in line number 1026 it is subtracting CONSTRT by 4. Then it is reserving space for two word size, and assigning 80H to first word (at line number 1028) and then another word at line number 1030.

```
1012 ORG 0
1014 CONSTRT EQU $
1016..................
1018..................
1020..................
1022..................
1024..................
1026 ORG $ - CONSTRT -  4
1028 DW 80H
1030 DW ?
1032..................
1034..................
```

What is the intention of this code.

Comment: Thanks Hans, i appreciate, but when I go through net I found that $ sign means "this address" or "current address"

Comment: Yes, so right after `ORG 0`, it's equivalent to `CONSTRT = 0` because `$` expands to `0`.  Except in assemblers where it's only a text substitution, but that wouldn't make sense because then the 2nd ORG line would be `ORG $ - $ - 4`.  Without more details on what assembler you're using (like [people told you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56612533/use-of-dollar-sign-while-declaring-segments#comment99799865_56612533) on your first version of this question), it's hard to answer in any more detail what this might do.  But probably it seeks backwards in the output by 4 bytes.